# Getting error when running nodemon server.js

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I'm using Visual Studio Code to run ExpressJs in debug mode.

***launch.json***

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\nodemon server.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I start debugging.

[image]

If I  run `nodemon server.js` in the terminal it works. The above error only appears when using Visual Studio Code debugging. I have tried the the following:

1. Remove *node_modules* and reinstall *node_modules*
2. Reinstall nodemon globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Visual Studio Code "*JavaScript Debug Terminal*". In the terminal I run command `nodemon server.js` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update this code line

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\nodemon server.js"
```

to

```
"program": "nodemon ${workspaceFolder}\server.js"
```

Comment: I just tried this and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can we try like this ?
"program": "nodemon ${workspaceFolder}\\server.js"

Comment: I tried it and still getting same error.